# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0

Tags: c#, odata

I added the **Odata v4 package** to my API, I noticed that it updated my **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi** package to **5.2.3** version. But when i try to use

> odata builder configuation in my WebApiConfig it showing error like
>   **'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0'**.

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

I searched this version(5.2.2) in my project but every thing is 5.2.3 and I updated all the packages too to solve this issue but failed.
Copy to Local property also true for System.Web.Http dll.
Any idea?

Comment: Check your web.config.  There might still be an assembly redirect in there redirecting all references to version 5.2.2.0.

Comment: Thanks, there is nothing I found in web.config,
This error is occuring when I add

config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));

in the webApiconfig

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Oberheim : I updated my answer, may be that will help you.

Comment: Same problem here. Any solutions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Visual studio solved this for me. The version conflicts are shown as warning and when I clicked it automatically added the binding redirect to my web config.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2.aspx

The binding redirect that solved my issue is,

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: I also have this in web.config, but I still get: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not "real" solution but a workaround:
I have changed the machine.config and replaced `<runtime />` with

```
  <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

so I works but if you have other web sites running...